# Ganache: How to find private keys of an account

Tags: ganache, public-key

#### How can I find a account's public key. Is it `Account Address`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the answer that fits your need best is "yes" if what you're asking is "should I send stuff to that public-key", but it's not exactly true.

I assume that you mean to ask about public-key and not private-key. I'm also answering for Bitcoin and cite the Ethereum white paper to do so. The address is not a natural ECC public-key.

From the updated Ethereum white paper https://ethereum.org/en/whitepaper/#notes

> A sophisticated reader may notice that in fact a Bitcoin address is the hash of the elliptic curve public key, and not the public key itself. However, it is in fact perfectly legitimate cryptographic terminology to refer to the pubkey hash as a public key itself. This is because Bitcoin's cryptography can be considered to be a custom digital signature algorithm, where the public key consists of the hash of the ECC pubkey, the signature consists of the ECC pubkey concatenated with the ECC signature, and the verification algorithm involves checking the ECC pubkey in the signature against the ECC pubkey hash provided as a public key and then verifying the ECC signature against the ECC pubkey.